# Angularjs Date format not constistant on browsers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have the following code:

```
app.filter('myDateFormat',function myDateFormat($filter){
    return function(text){
        var tempdate= new Date(text.replace(/-/g,"/"));
        return $filter('date')(tempdate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
});
```

Which takes the date from a database and puts it into the correct format.  Here is the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="rows in latestqs | limitTo:12">
   <a href="#pubres/{{ rows._id }}"> {{ rows.title }} </a>
   <br>
   <small>by {{ rows.group_name }} @ {{ rows._createdAt | myDateFormat }}</small>
 </li>
```

This works fine on chrome, but on IE9, it displays as:

NaN-NaN-NaN-0NaN NaN:NaN:NaN

Where as on chrome, its:

19-03-2014 14:00:19

Any ideas how i can get round this ?

Answer (score 1):

use momentjs in the filter, the best date library out there...

```
app.filter('myDateFormat',function myDateFormat($filter){
    return function(text){
        var moment = moment(text);
        if(moment.isValid) {
          var tempdate= new Date(moment.value());
          return $filter('date')(tempdate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
});
```

i have not tested this code..but should work well cross browser...

Comment: Effectively i used momentJS and worked in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I had a function that was like this:

```
function(text) {
  var d = new Date(text);
  return d;
}
```

The problem was the use of the `Date` constructor. IE9 would not properly parse some date/time strings. The ones I was having a problem with had less than 100 milliseconds. I noticed that if a date/time stamp had less than 100 milliseconds, two digits were included instead of three. The lack of a third digit caused IE9 to break. So, I added a zero (or two if the number of milliseconds was less than 10). Problem solved.